# Keep value in row if meets condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame df1. How can I save the column values after the last occurrence of `w.` For example in the case of `id 6` the last occurrence of `w` is at t8, therefore, I would like to save value occurring at `t9` as well the position of the last `w` in a new data frame.

Input:

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t6 t8 t9
  1  s  s  s  w  r  r  t  t  w  s
  2  s  s  s  o  o  w  t  t  o  s
  3  s  s  s  o  w  w  t  t  o  s
  4  s  s  s  o  o  w  t  t  o  s
  5  w  s  s  s  s  s  w  w  s  s
  6  s  s  s  w  t  t  w  w  w  s
```

Output:

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t6 t8 t9
  1                          w  s
  2                 w  t  t  o  s
  3                 w  t  t  o  s
  4                 w  t  t  o  s
  5                       w  s  s
  6                          w  s
```

Sample data:

```
df1<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), t1=c("s","s","s","s","w","s"), t2=c("s","s","s","s","s","s"),t3 = c("s","s","s","s","s","s"),
                    t4 = c("w","o","o","o","s","w"), t5 = c("r","o","w","o","s","t"), t6 = c("r","w","w","w","s","t"),
                    t7 = c("t","t","t","t","w","w"),t6 = c("t","t","t","t","w","w"), t8 = c("w","o","o","o","s","w"), t9=c("s","s","s","s","s","s")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The index to select the value would be which.max(x) using apply(df1, 1, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `apply` row-wise :

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) {
  ind <- max(which(x == 'w'))
  x[seq_len(ind - 1)] <- ''
  x
}))
df1

#  id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t6 t8 t9
#1  1                          w  s
#2  2                 w  t  t  o  s
#3  3                 w  t  t  o  s
#4  4                 w  t  t  o  s
#5  5                       w  s  s
#6  6                          w  s
```

`max(which(x == 'w'))` returns the index of last occurrence of `'w'` in the row.

---

Another option is to create matrix of row and column values that need to be replaced.We can use `max.col` with `ties.method = 'last'` which will give you the index of last occurrence of `'w'` in each row. Now we need to create a sequence from 2 to that number for each value in `cols` to create the matrix which can be used to replace with blank value.

```
cols <- max.col(df1[-1] == 'w', ties.method = 'last')
mat <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) cbind(x, seq(y)[-1]), 1:nrow(df1), cols))
df1[mat] <- ''
```